# "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" with UUID::toString, but not for Object::toString

Tags: java, intellij-idea

There are a lot of questions about this error but couldn't find an answer for this particular kind of situation. Given this interface:

```
interface Converter<IN, OUT> {
  OUT convert(IN in);
}
```

And this method:

```
public Converter<?, String> converter(java.lang.reflect.Type type) {
  if (type == UUID.class) {
    return <X>;
  }
}
```

When for X I use `UUID::toString`, I get the "cannot be referenced" error. But with `Object::toString`, I don't. This is in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.1.

I guess the question is, why does `Object::toString` work? That one doesn't take an argument either, so how can it implement an interface method that takes an argument?

---

[edit] I find that this works:

```
public Converter<UUID, String> converter(java.lang.reflect.Type type) {
  return UUID::toString;
}
```

So yeah, this has to do with type inference. In that case maybe the "non-static method" message is a little bit of a red herring?

Comment: You didn't provide sufficient code to reproduce, but the usual answer is that `?` erases to `Object`, so you can call any `Object` methods on a variable of that type. (And note that in the case of UUID, there's no difference in calling `toString`, so there's no point in having this separate one-way converter.)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think it's because using `?` actually compiles to `Object` and so the compiler won't let you use `UUID` which, during compile time, is not usable. Update: @chrylis gave a better explanation than me.

Comment: What type is `Type`?

Comment: Note that you can work around this by making the target type explicit: `return (Converter<UUID, String>)UUID::toString;`

Comment: As far as the compiler is concerned, the whole UUID is a red herring. It's the wrong type for an instance method, so it's searching for a static method that accepts `Object` and returns `String` and it's only finding the non-static `toString()`.

Comment: Yes, thanks @shmosel, that explains it. Feel free to add an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Can you use `Class` instead of `Type`?  Then you could write something like `public <T> Converter<T, String> converter(Class<T> type)`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, that would work too: `return T::toString;`